# Getting all required Jar for project

Tags: java, maven

I have a piece of code in my java project where I am getting all jar from classpath using-

> System.getProperty("java.class.path", ".");

When I am executing this on my local windows machine it's giving me the bunch of jar file. But when same code I tried to execute on Linux Box using command line, it's giving only one jar as following-

> /usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar

Any idea/suggestion will be highly appriciated.

Comment: Classes can be load dynamically.

Comment: I need to load the all jar which I have configured in pom.xml.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you read `java.class.path`? If you want to gather all required JARs and your're using Maven, you may try something like `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`, but there are many other ways.

Comment: I need to get the all module project jar which I have added in pom.xml, after getting the jar I am searching for a file if jar have contains that file or not.

Comment: Elements of the class path are separated by a platform-specific character specified in the path.separator property. So it will be different on Windows and Linux.

Comment: @deen Then reading `java.class.path` is a wrong approach. Who says that `java.class.path` contains all the dependencies from your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @lexicore, Can you guide me how I can achieve this because I'm able to execute this in my local windows machine using eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy all the dependencies you've defined in `pom.xml`, run

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

in the same directory and check `target/dependency`.

There are many other approaches like using the `maven-assembly-plugin` or building a fat JAR with `maven-shade-plugin`.